# VBA partial string CountIf inside of cell formulas (not Values)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have a worksheet with a bunch of linked cells set to a UNC path. For example, lets say that Cell A1 is equal to:

```
='\\corp\StackOverflow\[Example01.xlsx]TestSheet'!$A$1
```

and Cell A2 is equal to:

```
='\\corp\StackOverflow\[Example02.xlsx]TestSheet'!$A$1
```

Is there a way to have a CountIf for a partial string of "StackOverflow" for the entire worksheet? It would return a 2.

```
Sub Search()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    s = "StackOverflow"

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set r = ws.Cells
            i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, "*" & s & "*")
            MsgBox ("i: " & i)
        Next ws
End Sub
```

This is what I am using, but it always returns a 0 because I think it only looks at the Values. I want it to look inside of the formula (even if that cell normally returns a #REF! error). And yes, if it could look at the entire worksheet's cells, because I want to use it on a For Each ws basis.

Comment: Maybe use `Find`/`FindNext` and look in `xlFormulas`...

Answer (score 0):

One can search the text of formula cells for a specific string and increase the counter.

```
Sub Search()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    s = lcase("StackOverflow")

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each rng In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                If LCase(rng.Formula) Like "*" & s & "*" Then i = i + 1
            Next
        Next ws
        MsgBox ("i: " & i)
End Sub
```